# Why Future class called as Future API in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I know what is API meaning of Software Engineering. 
But I have no idea about why Future class Called as Future API in Dart and Flutter. 
Can I know why it is called "Future API"?

Comment: Do you have a link where this is mentioned?

Comment: Why *isn't* it an API?  Every class provides an *interface*.  Interfaces are for *programming* against, and usually such programs are *applications*, so generally "interface" and "API" are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API simply means Application Programming Interface, and is in the world of programming used in many different contexts...It usually refers to a set of functions that you as the programmer can plug into to interact with some other software.

The simplest most straightforward version of an API to grasp is probably just an interface.

In this context, the "Future API" (If they referred to it in this way) simply defines the signature of the Future and says something about how you can interact with a Future. it's basically a definition that lets you know what to expect from the Future class and what you can do with it. In the same way, something like the Google Places API defines a set of "functions" that you can interact with that returns a certain type of data.